# Span Placement in Twitter Bootstrap HTML / CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, html

[image]

I'm having a small HTML/CSS Bootstrap problem here.  Basically I have a span4 with a picture on the left side then a span8 with a paragraph describing the picture on the right side.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cent text-center">
    <div class="row box" style="border:1px solid #CCC; padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;">
     <div class="span4" style="height:200px;"><div class="profile pro"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png" /></div><!----profile END---></div><!---span4--->
   <div class="span8 section">
   <h3 align="center">Title</h3>
   <div class="team">
   <p class="team">this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture.</p>

   </div><!---team END--->
   </div><!---span8--->
    </div><!---Row END--->
   </div><!----cent END--->
   </div><!--container END-->



.cent{
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    width:auto;
    }

    .section {
    padding-top:20px;
    margin:auto;
    }

.team {
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    max-width:600px;!important
    padding-left:20px;!important
    padding-right:20px;!important
    }

    .profile {
        max-width:200px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:auto;
        padding-top:10px;
        }

        .pro {
            padding-left:100px;!important
            }

            .box {
                background:#FFF;
                border:1px solid #CCC; 
                box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #CCC; 
                padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
                -moz-border-radius: 7px;
                border-radius: 7px;
                min-height:220px;
                }
```

Now the only thing I want to do is invert the code so that the picture is now on the left and the description on the right but it seems when I do that the span4 does not go on the side of the `span8` but instead under it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cent text-center">
    <div class="row box" style="border:1px solid #CCC; padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;">
   <div class="span8 section">
   <h3 align="center">Title</h3>
   <div class="team">
   <p class="team">this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture.</p>
   <div class="span4" style="height:200px;"><div class="profile pro"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png" /></div><!----profile END---></div><!---span4--->
   </div><!---team END--->
   </div><!---span8--->
    </div><!---Row END--->
   </div><!----cent END--->
   </div><!--container END-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary code in there. Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for but instead of trying to figure out the code you provided, I just started fresh and provided a much cleaner way of doing what you want to accomplish.

You should modify your question as you ask for what already is. At the top you say: "basically I have a span4 with a picture on the left side then a span8 with a paragraph describing the picture on the right side." but then down below you say "now the only thing I want to do is invert the code so that the picture is now on the left and the description on the rite but it seems when I do that the span4 does not go on the side of the span8 but instead under it."

the key is to use the "float" property.

here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span4">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="span8-text">
             <h3>Title</h3>

            <p>this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture this is the description about the picture.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
.span4 {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
.span8 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
}
```

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h69Bh/

Comment: I tried this out seems like I get more of a problem because both elements the description and the picture goes to the corner of the page.. like the description would go all the way to the left leaving a huge gap in between the picture that goes all the way to the right.

Comment: you have to add a specified width for the "container" class or you can wrap teh span4 and sapn 8 into another <div> and give that <div> margin: 0 auto; and then a specified width (say 600px). That will center content and prevent the gap

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `float` property `span8 float:left` and `span4 float:right`

Take a look [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/BQ2q5/)

Comment: thats not working it still on the bottom of the span 8 instead of on the right of it

Comment: Try the demo.for span 8  you have to specify the width.

Answer (score 0):

This is it: 
add this in head section below all links to bootstrap cdn :

```
<style>
      img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
  </style>
```

and this in body tag:

```
<div class="container img-responsive">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
         description goes here
       </div>
       <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         <img src="1.jpg">  
       </div>

    </div>
    <div>
```

check responsiveness:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/c0zoq8e1/1/